# window.jQuery or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, zepto

```
(function($) {
// plugin code
})(window.jQuery);
```

Seems this code almost the same effect, as:

```
(function($) {
// plugin code
})(jQuery);
```

Should I use `window.jQuery` or `jQuery` for function argument? Does it make sense?

Same for Zepto, I've seen lots of people use `window.Zepto` in their plugins, but the code also works with just `Zepto`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference, `window` is the *super* global object in client-side JavaScript, all the functions and variables that are defined in the global context are methods and properties of the `window` object.

Comment: "window is *the* global object"?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Do you mean I should have written _window is the global object_ instead of _window is a global object_?

Comment: Yes ... well it's a suggestion.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot This is a good suggestion, I though that it can be confusing for some readers. A global object that other global _identifiers_ are methods/properties of it! :)

Comment: Undefined, indeed I see your point, though maybe exposure to this concept could lead to less confusion later. It's a fine line.

Comment: There is one difference; if jQuery is not on-page, then using the non-fully-resolved `jQuery` will throw an error, while `window.jQuery` will return `undefined`. So... if you are testing for the presence of jQuery, then you should use `window.jQuery` rather than `jQuery`.

Comment: Things start to change as we enter the world of ES Modules and Service Workers. Always best to be explicit when you can define namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same just like `$(document).ready(function(){..})` and `$(function(){..})`.

It's used to setting up a jQuery closure. The intention is to allow the variable $ to be used as a shortcut for jQuery without conflicting with other libraries and custom functions that also use $ as a variable name

This technique is often used by jQuery plugin authors to authorize their plugins. Check [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for more infos.

Answer (score 2):

`window.jQuery` is object defined in window global object. `window` could be skipped. When skipped it is supposed to we window.jQuery. Most of people do not use window.jQuery rather use `jQuery` or simply `$` and is more understandable also reduces the source code size.

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

You can read more over [here](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics).

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference. `!!window.jQuery` will return false if jQuery is not defined while `!!jQuery` will throw an error if jQuery is not defined.